# Should I use session cookies or HTTP Authentication?

Tags: http, authentication

Sessions are not a stateless method of user authentication, which seems to break the web as it does not lend itself to RESTful communication. Why are they so much more popular?

Why aren't more sites using HTTP Digest or Basic Auth type methodologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases sessions are used to store a server side state consisting of more than just a login name. And in many cases corporate identity is also important and you cannot design the basic/digest auth dialog.

Comment: The dialog can be designed according to http://www.berenddeboer.net/rest/authentication.html#login-page

Comment: @Treffynnon: thanks for that interesting page. As some devices only accept basic/digest auth this is a solution that might come handy.